# Is impredicative Set consistent with the excluded middle?

Tags: type-theory, coq

While studying Coq, I found a few references that [impredicative Set might not work well with classical axioms](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Universes.html), in particular the axiom of choice.

I'm working on a dependent type system based on the calculus of constructions (with Prop and Set), on which I intend to add Peirce's law on sets, as in the computability side it represents `call/cc` (capturing/resuming the whole computation).

My question is: is the calculus of constructions* with an impredicative Set, with the excluded middle working on sets (precisely, `forall P: Set, ((P -> False) -> P) -> P` being of type `Set`), *without the axiom of choice*, consistent? I didn't manage to find a reference for that.

*(* Would inductive types make any difference, from CoC to CIC?)*

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert, but my understating was not that it it was inconsistent, but that it implies proof irrelevance. That is, if $s,t:T$ then $s=t$.

This gives many undesirable properties, like having $1=2$, but I'm not sure it actually implies bottom.
[This answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4905/where-is-the-proof-that-coq-excluded-middle-is-consistent) had similar details.

Comment: How are you implementing $1=2$ in the calculus of constructions? In the calculus of inductive constructions, with objects of the inductive type `nat`, it certainly does imply False (the proof tactic in Coq is `discriminate` and the proof object is centered around a dependent pattern matching in the type `1=2`).

Comment: @Giles I should be more clear, my mistake. I think it is contradictory if pattern matching is allowed, since that lets you discriminate between different  proofs. I'll update this when I get a chance.

Comment: I'm initially designing my type system _without_ inductive types (and pattern matching), but I do intend to add them later. If this changes things (on regard to the excluded middle), that would be useful information as well.

Comment: Also, on that post they say "[...] since 2 is a complete lattice [...]", I have no idea what that means. :(

Comment: @paulotorrens: $2$ is some type-theoretic version of the two-element set $\{0,1\}$. With the standard (numeric) partial order, this set becomes a lattice which happens to be complete (have suprema and infima of arbitrary subsets). Completeness only holds if some version of the law of excluded middle is available; a constructive substitute which is always complete is the lattice of all subsets of $\{\heartsuit\}$, which contains $\emptyset$ and $\{\heartsuit\}$ (corresponding to $0$ and $1$), but potentially also further elements.